# How can you compare a cell value with all the previous cells?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I want to do something like if the cell is smaller than every other cell before it, it will do something and it should work for every cell. So if I have cells A1 to A7, A2 should check if it is smaller than A1, and so on to A7 should check if it is smaller than all the numbers from A1 to A6. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Your formula can start with reference to A2 because A1 can't be smaller than everything before it.  Say you formulas are in column B.  In B2:

```
=IF(A2<MIN(A$1:A1),formula if true,formula if false)
```

Copy that down column B as needed.  The `$` locks A1 as the start of the range and the second number will increment as you copy the formula down.

For each associated value in column A, it will test whether that value is less than the lowest value above it.

Answer (score 0):

Lock half of the reference using `$`. So, in cell `A2` enter `IF(A2<MIN(A$1:A1), This, That)`

Comment: Well that would almost work, i have found the solution also thanks to you. Final reference is IF(A2<SMALL($A$1:A2;2);10;0) as i need it to be smaller than second smallest, which will, in the end work like if the cell is the actuall unique smallest cell, it will input 10, otherwise 0.